# In C++, using Code::Blocks, can't open a file, although it exists and the path should be correct

Tags: c++, file, sdl, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks and the SDL library to create a simple computer game.
I have been following some tutorials, and have created a functional game of tic tac toe. 
While the project didn't have any specific instructions, I created a template that could be used with other games.
Using that template, I created a new project, where I'd have an image of Yoshi running.
However, in this new project, when I use a function that requires to open a file, it never works. For example:

```
if ( (Surf_Anim = CSurface::OnLoad("yoshi.bmp")) == NULL)
    return false;
```

always returns false, even though the yoshi.bmp exists, and the OnLoad function is exactely the same as in the Tic Tac Toe project.

I have placed copies of the yoshi.bmp image next to the executable, and it still doesn't work. (In the functional TicTacToe project, the images were on the same directory as the project)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: After confirming that manipulation of text files worked properly, I edited the CSurface::OnLoad function, like this:

```
SDL_Surface* CSurface::OnLoad(char* File)
{
  SDL_Surface* Surf_Temp = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* Surf_Return = NULL;

  if((Surf_Temp = SDL_LoadBMP(File)) == NULL)
    {
      return NULL;
    }

  printf ("Loafing worked\n");

  Surf_Return = SDL_DisplayFormat (Surf_Temp);
  SDL_FreeSurface(Surf_Temp);

  if (Surf_Return == NULL)
    printf ("SDL_DisplayFormat didn't\n");

  return Surf_Return;
}
```

Both printf functions were executed. I suppose this problem has to do with the way I used SDL functions. Anyway, everything was done in the same way in a perfectly working project. The image yoshi.bmp, is, like the ones on the said working project, a bit map with 24 bit colours...

Comment: try using full path to the file.

Comment: don't use code::blocks. It's awful.

Comment: @TonyTheLion What are the alternatives?

Comment: @WaleedKhan, NetBeans, Eclipse etc. Anyway - it's crazy the number of folks who apparently cannot distinguish between the IDE and the compiler... As to the real problem at hand - check the settings of the project for the something like the run directory (where the binary is executed and check that the image is in that directory.)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I've tried that, and it didn't work...

Comment: @Nim There's something called "Execution working dir" which is set at the correct place...

Comment: Actually, I tried manipulating text files with the fopen and fclose functions, and it seems to work. Only the SDL functions to load images seem not to be working... Yet, they are exactely the same as the ones on the tictactoe perfectly functional project...

Comment: AH! I just found out what it was! Sorry for bothering you, and thanks for your advice!

What happens, I imagine, is that the Dysplay Format thing had not been set previously, so the SDL_DisplayFormat function couldn't know what to do... I put the SDL_SetVideoMode function being called before this stuff, and everything works nicely!

I had been dealing with this problem for 4 days... I must be retarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DisplayFormat function couldn't work because the pixel format and colors of the video framebuffer had not been previously set using the function  SDL_SetVideoMode.

Calling this function before trying to load the image, solved the problem.